# Printing from a dictionary Java

Tags: java, dictionary, printing

I would like to print the occurrence of each character in a text using a dictionary system:

Ex: Text is "I like apples"

Console output looks like:

'i' has an occurrence of 2 times on positions: 1, 4

'l' has an occurrence of 2 times on positions: 3, 11

..

So far I've got this

```
String text = "text";
HashMap<Integer, String> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    dictionary.put(i, String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)));
}
```

Basically just adding each letter to a key value in the dictionary, but I can't figure out how to do the print...

Comment: @Aomine I believe this is not truly a duplicate: the other question wants a solution using regex - this one wants to use a dictionary and also wants positions.  Different problems.

Comment: @CPerkins sure thing, reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses a dictionary and prints the correct answer in the exact format requested:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    String text = "i like apples";  
    char[] textArray = text.toCharArray();

    //a dictionary that will hold the letter as the key and a list of it's positions as the value.
    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> dictionary = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    //loop through the text to check each letter
    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {            

        //if you've already checked this letter, skip to the next one
        if(dictionary.containsKey(textArray[i])) {
            continue;
        }       

        //add the letter's position to its position list
        ArrayList<Integer> positionList = new ArrayList<>();
        positionList.add(i);

        //compare the remaining letters in the text to the current letter
        for (int j = i+1; j < textArray.length; j++) {

                //if a letter matches, add it's position to the list
                if(textArray[i] == textArray[j]) {
                positionList.add(j);
            }   
        }               

        //add the letter and its list of positions to the dictionary
        dictionary.put(textArray[i], positionList);
    }

    //format the response
    for(char key : dictionary.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        positions = dictionary.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + " has an occurance of " + positions.size() + " on positions: " + positions);           
        }
    }
}
```

Prints to console:

```
  has an occurance of 2 on positions: [1, 6]
p has an occurance of 2 on positions: [8, 9]
a has an occurance of 1 on positions: [7]
s has an occurance of 1 on positions: [12]
e has an occurance of 2 on positions: [5, 11]
i has an occurance of 2 on positions: [0, 3]
k has an occurance of 1 on positions: [4]
l has an occurance of 2 on positions: [2, 10]
```

Comment: are you required to use dictionary?

Comment: Yes I am, I know how to write a solution to this without using a dictionary, in any case this solution is more up my alley, I can actually understand it better than the initial one. Thanks for the great answer!!

Comment: your welcome, I can add comments in the code if you want explanation on any of it lmk

Comment: That would also be helpful! Tho I kinda understand how this works, mostly... XD

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would go about it:

```
String[] tempArray = data.split("");
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, tempArray.length)            
         .boxed()
         .collect(groupingBy(index -> tempArray[index-1].toUpperCase()))
         .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " has an occurrence of " +
                     v.size() + " times on positions " + v.stream()
                    .map(Object::toString).collect(joining(","))));
```

- first split the string into their individual characters represented as strings
- utilise `IntStream.range` to generate the indices
- utilise `groupingBy` to group by the individual characters and have the values as a `List<Integer>` representing the indices that characters appear in
- finally, use `forEach` to format the data and print to the console.

given data is set as follows:

```
String data = "I like apples";
```

this yields the output:

```
P has an occurrence of 2 times on positions 9,10
  has an occurrence of 2 times on positions 2,7
A has an occurrence of 1 times on positions 8
S has an occurrence of 1 times on positions 13
E has an occurrence of 2 times on positions 6,12
I has an occurrence of 2 times on positions 1,4
K has an occurrence of 1 times on positions 5
L has an occurrence of 2 times on positions 3,11
```

Note that the above solution considers a space as a character as well, if you don't want this in the output then use a `filter` operation to exclude it:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, tempArray.length)
         .filter(index -> !tempArray[index-1].trim().isEmpty())
         .boxed()
         .collect(groupingBy(index -> tempArray[index-1].toUpperCase()))
         .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " has an occurrence of " +
                     v.size() + " times on positions " + v.stream()
                    .map(Object::toString).collect(joining(","))));
```

Comment: Does IntStream work like a dictionary as well? I do not understand how a dictionary is created in this case, from the lessons I've been learning I read that you can create a dictionary using HashMap so I went ahead using that, and there was an exercise asking to do the above but I could not figure out how to do the prints for the exercise.

Comment: @David the `groupingBy` creates the dictionary (known as a Map in java). so for example, if you did `Map<String, List<Integer>> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, tempArray.length)
                .filter(index -> !tempArray[index-1].trim().isEmpty())
                .boxed()
                .collect(groupingBy(index -> tempArray[index - 1].toUpperCase()));` you'd have a dictionary of elements to their indices. you can then iterate over it to format it how you want.

Comment: Oh, ok, cool, I'll need to read more about the functionalities offered by IntStream. Thanks for the great response!! Tho I'll need to go and practice some more of the basics since I'm getting into waaay to complex stuff...

Answer (score 2):

You can try as as below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericPlayAround {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String text = "I like apples";
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> dictionary = new HashMap<Character, List<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= text.length(); i++) {
            Character c = text.charAt(i-1);
            List<Integer> list;
            if (dictionary.containsKey(c)) {
                list = dictionary.get(c);
            }
            else {
                list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                dictionary.put(c, list);

            }
            list.add(i);
        }

        System.out.println(dictionary);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
{ =[2, 7], p=[9, 10], a=[8], s=[13], e=[6, 12], I=[1], i=[4], k=[5], l=[3, 11]}
```